# Save file with BOM preserved

Tags: vim

I'm trying to save UTF-8 file with BOM preserved. For some reason the line `setglobal bomb` doesn't work for me: the file is saved as plain UTF-8.

Here are the tech details about my Vim:

- gvim 8.1.1 on Windows 7, with no plugins or custom patches added
- `:echo has('multi_byte')` shows `1`

Here is my _vimrc:

```
if has('multi_byte')
  if &termencoding == ''
    let &termencoding = &encoding
  endif
  set encoding=utf-8
  setglobal fileencoding=utf-8
  setglobal bomb " Doesn't work?
endif

set laststatus=2
if has("statusline")
  set statusline=%<%f\ %h%m%r%=%{\"[\".(&fenc==\"\"?&enc:&fenc).((exists(\"+bomb\")\ &&\ &bomb)?\",B\":\"\").\"]\ \"}%k\ %-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P
endif
```

## Edit:

Well, as I later discovered, it looks like a bug. Steps to reproduce:

1. Open Vim. Notice that there is no BOM indicator in status line.
2. Write something (`foo`)
3. Run `:enew!`
4. Notice that new file have BOM indicator.

So, my question: how could I have BOM enabled immediately on Vim startup (i.e. on step 1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `:help 'bomb'`:

> local to buffer

From `:help :setglobal`:

> ```
>         Command          global value       local value
>       :set option=value      set                set
>  :setlocal option=value       -                 set
> :setglobal option=value      set                 -
> ```

Thus, *not* a bug: your `setglobal bomb` sets the global option, but *doesn't* set the local option of your starting buffer. Change `setglobal bomb` to `set bomb` in order to affect your starting buffer as well.

Comment: Hmm, but it seems `setglobal` should have its own advantages? My code is taken from Vim Wiki, [Working with Unicode](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Working_with_Unicode) page.

Comment: I don't know why it's written as it is. I didn't write it :P See `:help startup` for the sequence: #2 is creation of initial buffers, #3 is loading of RC files. `setglobal` will not affect already created buffers, by design. However, the warning does make a good point: why do you need BOM anyway? I've never ever needed it, and only ever raged against Windows editors when they "helpfully" added it. Added to the fact that Vim will turn `'bomb'` on when a file with BOM is read, I'd suggest only doing `:setlocal bomb` when you really need it (and if you do it very often, make a command or mapping)

Comment: (Disclaimer: Not implying everything I write is perfect - far from it, I do stupid things daily, Just that I can't explain why it's written as it is.)